# Arithmetic Progression Question: I have no numbers and I am not sure how to proceed

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

Three numbers are consecutive terms of a geometric progression. If we add 2 to the second number, the
new progression becomes arithmetic. If we add 9 to the third number, the progression becomes geometric.
Find the original numbers.

Comment: Start by writing down what you do know.  The three numbers are $a,ar,ar^2$  Now use the second and third sentences to write equations.  Presumably the third sentence still has the $2$ added to the second number before you add the $9$.  You will have two equations in the two unknowns $a,r$

Comment: @RossMillikan I did exactly that but this is where I get stuck. What common thing do these three equations have when I have no numbers? a+ar+ar^2; a+ar+ar^2+2; a+ar+ar^2+11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have an arithmetic progression, you need a common difference.

The second talks of adding $2$ to the second number, so $a,ar+2,ar^2$ is an arithmetic progression, so $ar^2-(ar+2)=(ar+2)-a$.

Then you get back to geometric by adding $9$ to the third, so $\frac {ar+2}a=\frac {ar^2+9}{ar+2}$.

There are your two equations.